# Bondal-Orlov Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I'm trying to read a proof of the reconstruction theorem by Bondal and Orlov asserting that an equivalence of derived categories of coherent sheaves $F:D^b(X)\cong D^b(Y)$ gives isomorphism between smooth projective schemes $X$ and $Y$ with (dual) canonical bundle ample. Precisely the one that can be found sketched here [https://www.math.ucla.edu/~rouquier/papers/leeds.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erouquier/papers/leeds.pdf) (at p. 367).

Now, I mainly would like to ask for some references in order to understand this proof, because many things remain mysterious to me (I didn't even get where do we use some of the hypothesis we made on the schemes). Anyway I'll write down a first question that arose.

For a closed subset $Z\subseteq Y$ we set $D^b_Z(Y)$ the full subcategory of $D^b(X)$ of complexes with all cohomology sheaves supported in $Z$. I belive that $F^{-1}(D^b_Z(Y))$ is thick since the argument is, and clearly it's stable under the Serre functor $S_X=-\otimes\omega_X[dim(X)]$, since Serre functors commute with equivalences. But why this would imply that it is of the form $D_{\Phi(Z)}(X)$ for a closed $\Phi(Z)\subseteq X$? And why should $\Phi$ be injective between closed subsets of $Y$ into closed subsets of $X$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look into section 4.2.1 of the paper you are reading?

Comment: Yes, I tried to read it: I guess we need to use the correspondence between closed subsets and ideals of finite type, which are thick, which says that the latter are exactly those of the form $D^b_Z(X)$ (and we use $X$-perf=$D^b(X)$ since $X$ is smooth). Is that correct? Anyway I really should find more detailed references other than this paper, do you have any to suggest? Thank you

Comment: What about the original paper of Bondal and Orlov?